Wobble animation in text-path issue
I am trying to create an alert to broadcast via stream elements.
I want the user's text, which is dynamic, to fit a path that draws a curve. Said text, I want it to have the wobble animation. If the text is drawn normally, the animation works perfectly. On the other hand, when going through a path, it does not play or does so as if it were an entire block of text and not the letters independently.
HTML
<div class="text-container">
    <div class="awsome-text-container">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
            <path id="curve" d="M -35,50 L-35,325 Q-35,375 65,375 L175,375" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
            <text font-size="85px">
                <textPath id="username-container" href="#curve"></textPath>
            </text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>


CSS
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caprasimo');

* {
    font-family: 'Caprasimo', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.awsome-text-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: visible;
}

.animated-letter {
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.text-container {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

@keyframes wobble {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
    }
    15% {
        transform: translateX(-2px) rotate(-2deg);
    }
    30% {
        transform: translateX(2px) rotate(2deg);
    }
    45% {
        transform: translateX(-1.5px) rotate(-1.5deg);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateX(1.5px) rotate(1.5deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateX(-1px) rotate(-1deg);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translateX(1px) rotate(1deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
    }
}


JS
function stringToAnimatedHTML(s, anim) {
    const stringAsArray = s.split('');
    const animationDuration = '1.5s';

    const animatedLetters = stringAsArray.map((letter, index) => {
        const randomDelay = Math.random() * 1;
        const transformValues = `translateX(${Math.random() * 2 - 1}px)`;
        return `<tspan class="animated-letter ${anim}" style="animation-duration: ${animationDuration}; animation-delay: ${randomDelay}s; transform: ${transformValues};">${letter}</tspan>`;
    });

    return animatedLetters.join('');
}

const name = '{{name}}';
const animation = 'wobble';
const userNameContainer = document.querySelector('#username-container');
userNameContainer.innerHTML = stringToAnimatedHTML(name, animation);



I don't think any browsers will apply a transform to a tspan.

Any ideas on how to put the svg with the animation without using tspan? I'm trying to get chatgpt to give me the solution, but it's very far from finding the key

http://svg-wow.org/text-effects/text-effects.xhtml

Thank you very much Robert. Although I have no idea about this, you are giving me instructions to know where the problem is and to be able to continue investigating. I'll continue there and take some ideas from those in the link. Thanks again! :)
